# How can i add collection of entities in doctrine2 to main entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

I have the

```
class user 
{
    @manytomany    
    private $countries
}
```

and

```
class country {
    @manytomany
    private $user
}
```

Now when the new user is created then i want to add predefined list of countries to user

`$countries = $em->getRepository(Country)->findBy(array('population'=>'2000'))`

I want to know how can i add those all countries in user entity

Is it possible

`$user->addCountry($countries)`

Comment: [What have you tried to do?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: well i spend 8 hours on internet searching about it and could not find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it work?

```
class user
{
    private $countries;
    public function addCountries($countries) {
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            $this->countries[] = $country;
        }
    }
}
```